# Converting a Swagger YAML file to JSON from the command line

Tags: json, command-line, yaml, swagger

I'd like to convert a Swagger `YAML` file to `JSON` from the command line.  The plan is to use this command line during a CI job.  I've searched on google and found many solutions, but most of them use Python or Ruby, which I'd prefer not to use.  For example: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12218/convert-yaml-to-json

I'd like to do this without using Python or Ruby, and
I'd also like to be able to control the leading whitespace when formatting the JSON to match exactly the JSON that is output from Swagger's [editor.swagger.io](http://editor.swagger.io) editor, when you choose `File` -> `Download JSON`

All this means is that I'd like the whitespace padding to be four spaces, like so:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "API TITLE",
```

I haven't tried the Python method in the link above, but the Ruby method uses two space whitespace padding.  Perhaps there is a way to control that, but I don't want to use Ruby or Python in this solution anyway.

I'm sure that there are many "correct" answers to this question.  I am looking for the solution that is most elegant with the least number of dependencies.  Ideally, a diff of the resulting JSON file against a JSON file generated by the [editor.swagger.io](http://editor.swagger.io) should be empty.

Answer (score 27):

I think that you are looking for the [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) (now [OpenApi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator)) functionality:

Running

`swagger-codegen generate -i swagger.yaml -l swagger`

will out put a swagger.json in the same location.

*Update For CI:*
If you can install it on your build machine-  good for you.
If you can't - the github page has a link to a docker image with a nodejs server is available (to convert using a curl command as suggested in a different answer).

*Update For Docker:*
If you use Docker, try [swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli](https://hub.docker.com/r/swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli), there is an example for docker-compose that might help a few answers down by Fabian & ckeeney.

**Update about OpenApi:**

This question is about swagger, and a few years old. If you're just starting to use Swagger you should switch to OpenApi instead, and if you have existing swagger files, i suggest [migrating](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/migration-from-swagger-codegen.md).

Comment: I *do* like this answer, but a docker image is quite a heavy dependency.  There should be a way to send the YAML spec to the POST endpoint that `generator.swagger.io` points to, which itself uses `swagger-codegen` but I can't figure out how to send a spec in the POST body :-/

Comment: I just did an *npm install -g swagger-codegen* and it did not include that command!  When I installed *npm install -g swagger-codegen-cli* the swagger-codegen-cli was available.

Comment: The install scripts fail currently, because `central.maven.org` is not accessible using wget or curl. I was only able to download the jar files from a browser. BTW the Java dependency is a big con. It's awful that there's no plain php/nodejs tool that supports version 3.

Comment: When I tried using swagger codegen, the `swagger` output format was not supported by the version I got from brew.

Comment: @RobertP.Goldman probably because brew is downloading the latest version (3.+), which doesn't support 'swagger' as language, but 'openapi' or 'openapi-yaml'. To be able to use swagger, you need to use version 2.

Comment: With version 3 of swagger-codegen here is the command you can run to convert a YAML swagger file to JSON: `swagger-codegen generate -i swagger.yaml -l openapi -o output_dir`. Then your file will be in `output_dir/openapi.json`. To do JSON -> YAML just specify a JSON file instead of Swagger and change 'openapi' to 'openapi-yaml'.

Comment: I found that `openapi-generator` supported the OpenAPI specs I had. `swagger-codegen` is older, and also seems to have some bugs. I believe `openapi-generator` should always be preferred these days. @Liel Maybe update your answer?

Comment: @RobertP.Goldman updated it in hope the next visitors won't waste time on the outdated swagger tool.

Answer (score 11):

Using [yamljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yamljs):

```
yaml2json swagger.yaml -p -i4
```

The output from this command diff'd against the JSON output from [editor.swagger.io](http://editor.swagger.io) produces an empty diff.

This is indeed what I'm looking for, but it brings in a huge dependency (node).  I'm hoping for something even lighter, yet equally as elegant as this.

Comment: There is a serious "con" with that way: cross-file relations are not translated. Example: `$ref: 'Pet.yaml'` should be translated to `$ref: 'Pet.json'`

Answer (score 11):

#### swagger-codegen cli interface

As [Liel has already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776563/5750032), you can run

`swagger-codegen generate -i swagger.yaml -l swagger`

#### Docker

If you use Docker, then I suggest you try [swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli](https://hub.docker.com/r/swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli/).

You can generate a json file using docker with the following command:

`docker run -v ./docs:/docs swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli generate -i /docs/swagger.yaml -l swagger -o /docs`

I like to setup a `docker-compose.yml` to "alias" this command for easy reuse:

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
  gen-swagger:
    volumes:
      - ./docs:/docs
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli
    command: generate -i /docs/swagger.yaml -l swagger -o /docs
```

And now I can just run `docker-compose run gen-swagger`

Comment: This is a good answer -- maybe edit it into Liel's to make a single, comprehensive answer?

Answer (score 11):

Another possibility to convert a swagger.yml file to swagger.json is a NPM package called [swagger-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-cli).

```
npm install -g swagger-cli
```

Then you can convert a yml to json file:

```
swagger-cli bundle -o api-spec.json api-spec.yml
```

Comment: Good answer, except that the question asks for minimum dependencies.  If you are are already a Node user, this is great. Otherwise, not so much. But there must be a way to use `swagger-cli` from a Docker image.

Comment: Looks like there's a docker image for this now: https://hub.docker.com/r/jeanberu/swagger-cli

`docker run --rm -v $PWD/pkg/libv1/api/openapi:/openapi jeanberu/swagger-cli swagger-cli bundle -o /openapi/common.json /openapi/common.yaml`

Answer (score 9):

For version **swagger-codegen 3.0.4**

Use

`swagger-codegen generate -i my_yaml.yaml -l openapi`

to get a `.json`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the online swagger codegen project to do this:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{
  \"spec\": {}
}" "https://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/clients/swagger-yaml"
```

Put the value of your swagger definition in the `spec` object.  You'll get a link to download the converted & validated spec, in yaml format.

For options, take a look here:

http://generator.swagger.io/

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I'm looking for, but reverse: I want to convert from YAML to JSON.  I'd assume that instead I'd want to use `https://generator.swagger.io/api/gen/clients/swagger` and perhaps use the mimetime `application/x-yaml` ?  For argument's sake I tried using a JSON file and converting to yaml but both your command line and the api-explorer on `http://generator.swagger.io` don't seem to like the `spec` field.  Any exact command line example for how to use the `spec` field in the POST body?  I'd suggest adding `default` value for this endpoint illustrating this...

Comment: The generator doesn't support that right now but it can.  I've opened this issue, which you can track for progress:  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/1903

Answer (score 3):

I'd use https://openapi-generator.tech/

It's an npm install (I just used it locally `npm install @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli`) and then

```
npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i source.yaml -g openapi -o outputdir
```

Answer (score 0):

For a gradle with Kotlin, I've written in my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory
import java.nio.file.Path
```

And then in a some task like `compileJava`code for conversion:

```
val compileJava: Task by tasks.getting {
  val openApiDir = "${rootProject.projectDir}/openapi"    
  val json: JsonNode? = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory())
    .readTree(Path.of("$openApiDir/openapi.yaml").toFile())
  ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
    .writeValue(Path.of("$openApiDir/openapi.json").toFile(), json)
}
```