# How to convert JSON to Swagger YAML programmatically? Is there a REST API to do it?

Tags: json, yaml, swagger

I want to automate a process where I want to convert a JSON file to a YAML file particularly in the format of Swagger YAML. I have tried python and npm libraries but they dont give the same YAML. Is there a Swagger REST API to do the job?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a Swagger YAML file to JSON from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733253/converting-a-swagger-yaml-file-to-json-from-the-command-line)

Comment: The linked question says YAML->JSON but the mentioned tools and APIs also support JSON->YAML conversion.

Comment: are you pointing at http://generator.swagger.io/ ? I am fairly new to REST API usage. I have a test.json file and I need to have test.yaml file. Can I do it using the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

The REST way-

curl -X POST \
  https://generator3.swagger.io/api/generate \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d @file-name.json -o result.zip

Or else

curl -X POST \
  https://generator3.swagger.io/api/generate \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "spec" : "Key1: Value1, Key2: Value2",
  "lang" : "openapi-yaml",
  "type" : "CLIENT",
  "codegenVersion" : "V3"
}' -o result.zip