# How to convert open api YAML structure to json

Tags: node.js, swagger

I want to make my UI to display all the information about the API.

Can you please tell me the best way to convert YAML structure to json?

Comment: https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-to-json#Sample check this page

Comment: you can use yamljs from npm this is popular one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an OpenAPI/Swagger YAML file to JSON from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733253/113116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime i was also went through this issue and I solve them by using the online tools example : https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json. that convert YAML structured file into JSON structured  file .

but if you need a Javascript parser you can use [js-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml)

you can use it to convert yaml to json with your js code.